# Notificaciones automáticas

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, notificaciones

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación multi plataforma en Xamarin forms con notificaciones integradas.

¿Hay alguna manera de incluir notificaciones automáticas cuando un usuario sube una noticia a la aplicación?

Tengo implementada toda la parte de la noticia, la cual se sube al servidor y se hace visible para el resto de usuarios.

Comment: Tenes que usar push notifications de azure, porque parece ser que App Center ya esta quedando obsoleto.

Answer (score 0):

Pues lo que necesitas es implementar notificaciones [push](https://www.mdirector.com/sms-marketing/que-son-las-notificaciones-push.html) en tu aplicación, eso es posible a través de servicios de cloud como azure o [visual studio app center](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TT11e_YCRwI&t=306s), pero por debajo lo más común es utilizar Firebase para realmente enviar las notificaciones en Android y para IOS es Apple quien gestiona las notificaciones.